# Употребление глаголов сбить  и  взбить

Tags: лексика

Как правильно употреблять глаголы сбить и взбить? Например к майонезу: сбить или взбить? имеет ли значение характер движения - круговое или сверху вниз?

Answer (score 12):

Глагол сбить имеет значение  "ударом, толчком сдвинуть с места, заставить упасть, отделить от чего-либо, сшибить".

Глагол "взбить" -  сделать пышным, рыхлым, мягким лёгкими быстрыми ударами (рук или какого-л. приспособления). Раньше (в словаре Ушакова например) действительно отмечалось направление движения снизу вверх, это одно из значений приставки вз- (сравните взлететь, взмахнуть, взобраться, взойти). Миксеров и блендеров не было. А теперь неважно, остался элемент значения - сделать пышным с помощью ударов.

Путаница с глаголом сбить, я думаю, объясняется фонетическими причинами: похожестью, нечеткостью  произношения в устной речи.

Comment: Глагол "сбить" имеет 11 значений ("Грамота.ру", орфографический словарь). В 11-м пункте объяснение следующее: "взбивая, смешивая, превратить в однородную массу. Н-р: с. желтки,с. масло, с. крем". И когда идет процесс взбивания, то получается и пышная, и мягкая масса. Наверное, корректны оба варианта: _сбить белок, сливки и т. д., взбить белок, сливки.

Answer (score 7):

По Ожегову Сбить- 2 омонима. У "Сбить-2" есть значение "ударами превратить в плотную массу". Сбить масло,Сбить сливки. Майонез всё-таки взбить, мы его превращаем в мягкую воздушную массу, а не в плотную.А вот сливки можно и взбить - сделать пышными, и сбить - превратить в масло. Только это разный результат.

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Но, проблема в том, что как раз-таки майонез не мягкая воздушная масса, там не должно быть воздушных пузырьков(это не безе), а плотная за счет эмульгирования растительного масла. Отсюда и возник вопрос.

Comment: Не думаю. Ингредиенты майонеза всё же взбивают, например, яйца. Майонез - соус. а соусы взбивают,как и сливки в десертах.Если все ингредиенты смешать и взбить, то масса будет мягкая, воздушная, т.е. взбитая (она даже увеличивается в объёме). Если сметану сбивать в масло, её объём не увеличивается, а уменьшается на выходе, а у майонеза увеличивается. Мне видится процесс взбивания, а не сбивания.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, наверное, этим ответом вы утвердили меня во мнении, что майонез сбивают. т к в объеме майонез точно не увеличивается и  масса не становится воздушной, а плотной, как и в случае с маслом.